# Python knap sack problem with recursion tree

Tags: python, recursion, knapsack-problem

Hello I have 5 blanks on the Python code below
in bmax_val() and bfast_max() functions

I'm trying to draw recursion tree as a result but it's too difficult to solve this problem

I tried to put
indent = "    " * (level + 1) \n
display(sub_lst, avail, level)
into the blank but still, I'm struggling with it...

is there someone who can help me to solve this?

```
def comp_result(sub_lst, avail, count, level): #
    nextitem = sub_lst[0]
    if nextitem[2] <= avail:
        chosen1, val1, count = bmax_val(sub_lst[1:],
                                        avail - nextitem[2], count, level)
        chosen1 = chosen1 + (nextitem,)
        val1 += nextitem[1]
        chosen2, val2, count = bmax_val(sub_lst[1:], avail, count, level)
        if val1 > val2:
            result = chosen1, val1, count
        else:
            result = chosen2, val2, count
    else:
        print(" " * 4 * (level + 1), "No left node")
        result = bmax_val(sub_lst[1:], avail, count, level)
    return result

def display(list_of_items, weight, level, flag = False):
    nlist = []
    for item in list_of_items:
        nlist.append(item[0])
    if flag:
        print(" " * 4 * level, nlist, weight, "Already solved")
    else:
        print(" " * 4 * level, nlist, weight)

def bmax_val(sub_lst, avail, count=0, level=-1):
    # blank
    # blank
    if sub_lst == [] or avail == 0:
        result = (), 0, count
        display([], avail, level, True)
        return result
    count += 1
    result = comp_result(sub_lst, avail, count, level)
    return result

def fast_result (sub_lst, avail, memo, count, level):
    nextitem = sub_lst[0]
    if nextitem[2] <= avail:
        chosen1, val1, count = bfast_max(sub_lst[1:],
                                         avail - nextitem[2], memo, count, level)
        chosen1 = chosen1 + (nextitem,)
        val1 += nextitem[1]
        chosen2, val2, count = bfast_max(sub_lst[1:],avail, memo, count, level)
        if val1 > val2:
            result = chosen1, val1, count
        else:
            result = chosen2, val2, count
    else:
        print(" " * 4 * (level + 1), "No left node")
        result = bfast_max(sub_lst[1:], avail, memo, count, level)
    return result

def bfast_max(sub_lst, avail, memo={}, count=0, level=-1):
    # blank
    if (len(sub_lst), avail) in memo:
        # blank
        return memo[(len(sub_lst), avail)] + (count,)
    # blank
    if sub_lst == [] or avail == 0:
        return (), 0, count
    count += 1
    result = fast_result(sub_lst, avail, memo, count, level)
    memo[(len(sub_lst), avail)] = result[0:2]
    return result

def create_item_list(): #
    names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    vals = [6, 7, 8, 9]
    weights = [3, 3, 2, 5]
    list_of_items = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        for i in range(len(names)):
            list_of_items.append((names[i], vals[i], weights[i]))
        return list_of_items

def main():
    items = create_item_list()
    taken, val, count = bmax_val(items, 5)
    print("\n")
    for item in taken:
        print(item)
    print("Total value of items taken =", val, "count =", count)

    print("\n")
    taken, val, count = bfast_max(items, 5)
    print("\n")
    for item in taken:
        print(item)
    print("Total value of items taken =", val, "count =", count)
main()
```

The following link represents the output format.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FIZU.png

Comment: If you're asking why those prints don't have any indentation, level is negative one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).